# Wave Header corrupted

Tags: c#, .net, wave

I want to do some changing on Wave file, then Play it Directly after doing that.

So I define a byte array to store the bytes of wave file on it as following:

```
byte[] byteArr;
byteArr = File.ReadAllBytes(dlg.FileName);
```

where dlg is an OpenFile Dialog.

Then I do a changing to sample bit rate of wave as following:

```
private void playSlectedWave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sample = 50000;
    MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream(byteArr);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    int length = (int)fs.Length-8;
    fs.Position = 22;
    short channels = br.ReadInt16();
    fs.Position = 34;
    short BitsPerSample = br.ReadInt16();
    byte[] arrfile = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Position = 0;
    fs.Read(arrfile, 0, arrfile.Length);
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
    bw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    bw.Write(arrfile, 0, 24); 
    bw.Write(sample);
    bw.Write((int)(sample* ((BitsPerSample * channels) / 8)));
    bw.Write((short)((BitsPerSample * channels) / 8));
    bw.Write(arrfile, 34, arrfile.Length - 34);
    SoundPlayer SP = new SoundPlayer(fs);
    SP.Play();
}
```

My question is that when it reaches the `SP.Play()` it throws an exception that says that the Wave Header is corrupted.

For more Information, I try the previous code but with FileStream instead of MemoryStream and it works fine for me .

Does Anyone know why?

Comment: @Mark Heath can you help here :)

Comment: @MattJohnson no.  Your last statement doesn't hold.

Comment: @MattJohnson when I searched for that I found that I must Modify only The value of ByteRate and BlockAlign when I change the sampleRate and I do that above .

Comment: I think no problem here. Anyhow that is not the rightway to use. Just set "fs.Position = 0;" before using SP, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SP.Stream.Position = 0;
```

It was a solution at least for my situation.

Answer (score 2):

Define your SoundPlayer SP outside of your sub/function or use

```
SP.PlaySync
```

---

```
SP.Play();
```

Is Async, after hitting that line you leave the Sub while it is still playing in the background and the memorystream is likely modified or removed from memory.

You are lucky that you only get an exception, there is a possibility that your program would just crash even when debugging without any exception.

Answer (score 0):

Format your desired audio file correctly to a .wav file!

I thought this would work:

```
soundPlayer.Stream.Position = 0;
```

But sadly, it compiled to no avail...

Try this site to format: http://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-wav